# Read file without 2D array and count rows and Columns

Tags: c, file, fgets

I'm looking for a solution to count rows and columns in a file.
I have while loop with that loads the file into a buffer.

```
 while(fgets(buffer, row_length,stdin) !=NULL)
```

Note: I can't print file into 2D array and i can't use fopen or alloc memory.

Comment: You are not loading the file into a buffer, you are loading all the rows one by one in your loop, how can you find the number of total rows? Also the number of columns is the length of the rows right? try to read what you have inside your `fgets`


(try to reason about it, we are not going to do an homework for you if you don't show at least a bit of effort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the row length, is that not already the column size? You said you can't use a 2D array, in fact you said nothing about whether you want to store this data so the buffer remains the same.

```
while(fgets(buffer, row_length + 2, myfile) != NULL) {
    rows++;
}
columns = row_length;
printf("COLUMNS: %d, ROWS: %d\n", columns, rows);
```